# Finding which unknowns are solvable in an underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following underdetermined system of equations:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
a+b&=&2 \\
4a+b+c+d&=&4 \\
2a+3b+c+d&=&1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(The actual values of the numerical constants aren't important - this is just a simple example.)

Although this is an underdetermined system, one can eliminate $c+d$ from these equations, leaving you with two equations in two unknowns (with the solution $a=7/4$, $b=1/4$), and a third equation in two unknowns ($c+d=-13/4$, if I haven't made an arithmetical error).

My question is: is there a general method  for determining which (if any) of the unknowns in an underdetermined system have exact solutions? I assume it involves the matrix of coefficients on the left-hand sides, i.e.,
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
for my above example. The actual system of equations I am interested in is bigger than my simple example above, so it's not obvious what the answer is just by looking at it.

Apologies if this is a problem with a well-known solution. I tried searching for it, but perhaps I don't know the correct terminology to be searching for (my background is in physics rather than mathematics).

Comment: Gauss-Jordan elimination method